# how to fix "can't resolve rxkotlin" in android

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-kotlin2

I'm using room database and need to add rxKotlin to my project, so when I use this code:

```
`implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.0.1'`
```

I get this error:

```
`ERROR: Failed to resolve: io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.0.1`
```

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find the list of versions you can choose from:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.reactivex.rxjava2/rxkotlin

Answer (score 0):

That's the correct repo

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.0.1-RC1'
```